# Finding the station to get off at in Vancouver

Tags: canada, buses, amtrak, vancouver, greyhound

I am travelling to Vancouver, BC by Greyhound bus and then catching the Amtrak train to Seattle Washington.

The greyhound will stop at Homer & Georgia, Burrard & Georgia, Station Street and the airport.

I am not sure if it is Station terminal or another one that is closest to the Amtrak connection.  Which greyhound station do I get off at in Vancouver?

Comment: Is there more than one Greyhound station in Vancouver? This would be unusual in my experience with Greyhound and other long distance buses in various countries, but I don't think I've used Greyhound in Vancouver so can't be 100% sure.

Comment: Yes, the greyhound will stop at Homer & Georgia, Burrard & Georgia, station street and the airport. I am not sure if it is station terminal or another one that is closest to the Amtrak connection

Comment: Your question will work better if you include that info. The more you leave out the more guesswork there is for people trying to help you.

Answer (score 8):

Most likely your Greyhound bus will only make a single stop in Vancouver itself, although it may make stops in nearby suburbs like Coquitlam.

The stop in Vancouver will be on Station Street, directly in front of the station that the Amtrak services leave from.

If you have some time between the two trips you could stroll down and enjoy the views over False Creek, or even hop on a False Creek Ferry for the short trip up-river.

Comment: Yep: This is the place on Greyhound's website: https://www.greyhound.ca/en/locations/terminal.aspx?city=731521 It's also the Amtrak terminus.

Comment: As someone who not only lives in Vancouver, but has been at that Greyhound station, I can confirm that this is correct.