# Where to find arrival/departure locations of Greyhound buses during online purchase?

Tags: public-transport, online-resources, tickets, buses, greyhound

I am looking for Greyhound tickets on their [website](https://www.greyhound.com/). I want to know how, in general, I can find the location of the bus station. For example, when I am leaving from New York City, I would guess that it will be leaving from the [Port Authority Bus Terminal](https://www.greyhound.com/en/locations/terminal.aspx?city=151239), but how can I ne sure about that? Is it listed somewhere, or will it be on my final ticket? For example, for [Vancouver there are multiple stations](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23190/finding-the-station-to-get-off-at-in-vancouver).

For [Bolt Bus](https://www.boltbus.com/), the departure/arrival location is clearly listed, but I couldn't find something like that for Greyhound. So, how do I to find out where (address) a Greyhound bus leaves/arrives, before booking the ticket?

Comment: In New York you should check which bus line actually services the route because they may be in different buildings in the bus station...

Comment: @Karlson What does "bus line" mean in this context? Just the bus' number? Will it be on my ticket?

Comment: It will be on your ticket but for example NY-Montreal can be run by Greyhound or by New York Trailways, which both leave from Port Authority but from different buildings.  The bus line and run may be on your ticket but gate may be wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [station selector](http://www.greyhound.com/en/locations/default.aspx)  which gives street address and map locations for many of their stops.

Comment: Ok, now I get my confusion, they have one station they call "New York", and other stations "New York Wall St" etc. That is confusing.

Comment: @Bernhard New York is a special case.  There are multiple starting stations for multiple bus lines and Greyhound being able to sell tickets to most of them will cause issues.  For Greyhound routes New York means Port Authority Bus Terminal 41st Street Building.

Comment: For your info. After I bought the ticket, the details of the station is listed on the itinerary.